# Prove that $a$ is a $p$th power in $k$ if only if it is in $K$

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field

Let $k\subset K$ be an extension having degree $[K:k]=n$ coprime to $p$. Prove that $a$ is a $p$th power in $k$ if only if it is in $K$

This is a problem in Galois theory - Miles Ried.
I'm learning Galois theory by myself. I can't understand $p$th power, i think is that $a^p$?

Comment: The problem asks you to prove that given any $a \in k$ there exists some $b \in k$ such that $a = b^p$ if and only if there exists some $b' \in K$ such that $a = (b')^p$.

Comment: I don't have ideal for this problem, can you help me answer or guide for me?

Answer (score 1):

If $p=2$ and $a$ is not a square in $k$, then the polynomial  $X^2-a $ is irreducible over $k$ and if it had a root  $\alpha \in K$ the tower $k\subset  k(\alpha)\subset K$ would imply that  $n$ is even, a contradiction.

If $p$ is odd and $a$ is not a $p$-th power in $k$, then $f(X)=X^p-a$ is irreducible and again we conclude that since $p$ is coprime to $n$ no root $\alpha$ of $f(X)$ can be contained in $K$.
That irreducibility of $f(X)$ is however a rather difficult theorem due to Capelli and proved in Lang's *Algebra*: Chapter VI, theorem 9.1, page 297 of the Third Edition.